# How to export XML from Qt?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

How to export XML from Qt?

I'm developing a question generator program and I need to export an XML file from Qt. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Hi, Andri! Have you tried something? Have you faced some problem? Describe us you problem.

Answer (score 4):

QXmlStreamWriter would help. Docs [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Generate_XML_programatically_in_Qt).